# Running a command line program from within c#?

Tags: c#, cmd

How do I run a command line program from within a c# program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a program or a batch file it is quite easy.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "MyProgram.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "1st_argument 2nd_argument" 
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

try
{
    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

This way you can pass arguments to your program or batch and decide to show or hide the executing console.

Regards.

Comment: if my argument are
"-q -dNODISPLAY -dSAFER -dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT -dSIMPLE -c save -f ps2ascii.ps "c:\test.pdf" -c quit >"c:\test.txt""
then 
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-q -dNODISPLAY -dSAFER -dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT -dSIMPLE -c save -f ps2ascii.ps "c:\test.pdf" -c quit >"c:\test.txt"" ?

Comment: That should do the trick, give it a try! What is clearly sure is that using arguments is not be a problem. The Process class has been designed for.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run a program, as from the command line, you would use Process.Start

It wouldn't show a command prompt though, unless it is a console app.

Comment: To get around this, you can launch `cmd.exe` with the `/C` switch and pass the name of the program you really want to run.

Comment: Sure, you could run it from cmd that way, but it won't show up as a console app or anything.  If you need it to be running from cmd then, you can do as Anon says.

Answer (score 4):

Process.start() is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Process.Start, which is in the System.Diagnostics namespace.

Note that you can supply a ProcessStartInfo object if you want to customize things, such as redirecting input/output.